# AngularJS - redirect after login without store the redirectTo path

Tags: angularjs

I use the 401 error handling globally within my AngularJS app.

The code below works, the next step for me is to implement the login functionality. Let's say it's done - but how to redirect the the path placed inside the `redirectTo` param after successful login ?

I can store that `redirectTo` path in the cookies or in the `$scope` variable - but I'd like to achieve this without any data storing.

```
myApp.factory('authHttpResponseInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) { }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                var path = $location.path();
                $location.path('/login').search('returnTo', path);
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}]);

....
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authHttpResponseInterceptor');
```

then my URL looks like `http://localhost:1234/app#/login?returnTo=%2Fedit-data%2F32`